# Cola de impresion de Windows se detiene al tratar de imprimir tickets grandes C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, impresión, impresora

Estoy tratando de imprimir un DataGridview directo a una impresora de tickets, ocupando una libreria que encontre llamada "LibPrintTicket" a continuacion el codigo que ocupo:

```
private void BtnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

        ticket.AddHeaderLine("MEDI-RET");
        ticket.AddHeaderLine("ORDEN: "+ NumeroOrdenTxt.Text + "  RUTA "+ RutaTxt.Text);
        ticket.AddHeaderLine("# CLIENTE: " + IdClienteTxt.Text + "  NOMBRE: " + NombreClienteTxt.Text);
        ticket.AddHeaderLine("FECHA: "+ FechaTxt.Text);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string a = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            string b = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[1].Value);
            string c = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[2].Value);
            string d = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[3].Value);
            string f = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[4].Value);
            ticket.AddSubHeaderLine(a + "|" + b);
            ticket.AddSubHeaderLine("|PZS:" + c + "  |PROV:" + d + "  |INV: " + f + "|");

        }
        ticket.PrintTicket("BIXOLON SRP-F310"); //Nombre de la impresora de tickets }
```

Funciona muy bien con tickets chicos, de unos 15 cm de largo, pero cruzando eso simplemente se traba toda la cola de impresion de Windows, no puedo acceder ni a las propiedades de las impresoras ni imprimir paginas de prueba, nada que tenga que ver con interactuar con impresoras, ni la de los tickets ni ninguna otra , todo esto hasta que elimine los archivos que se encuentran en la ruta `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` haciendo esto puedo reiniciar el servicio y todo funciona normalmente de nuevo, puedo seguir imprimiendo tickets chicos hasta que vuelva a mandar alguno grande

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hace unos momentos olvide eliminar estos archivos y despues de mucho tiempo (como 15 minutos) imprimio el ticket grande y todo funciono normal otra vez, pero los archivos continuan ahi

alguien tiene idea de a que se debera esto? , tengo que agregar que aunque ahora estoy usando la libreria para realizar la impresion, antes lo hacia de otra forma sin usar librerias y sucedia lo mismo

Comment: Deberías leer el manual de la impresora, quizás el buffer no soporta un documento tan grande. Haz la prueba en una impresora normal para descartar problema de código. Saludos.-

Comment: @CL. de hecho si pense eso y hice la prueba imprimiendo un archivo larguisimo de excel, facilmente del triple del que estoy tratando de imprimir y lo imprimio sin problemas, no creo que sea el buffer por que la impresora sigue imprimiendo si le mando una prueba desde un programa de la misma marca que prueba el driver opos

Comment: revisaste que en la configuración se le entregue el tamaño de hoja que debe imprimir?

Comment: @CL. justo despues de muchas pruebas me doy cuenta que el problema es el tama#o de la hoja, ahora estoy viendo como solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejare un código para imprimir prueba si te funciona puede ser que la libreria te este dando problema. Para implementar esto debes referenciar las dll desde el framework. El formato de papel debes definirlo.

```
/**** librerias a referenciar desde el framework *******/
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Management;
/******************************/
 public class Print
    {
        private PrintingPermission permission;
        private PrintDocument document;
        private bool landscape;
        private string printerName;
        private string paperSizes;

        public bool LandScape { get { return landscape; } set { landscape = value; } }
        public string PrinterName { get { return printerName; } set { printerName = value; } }
        public string PaperSizes { get { return paperSizes; } set { paperSizes = value; } }

        public Print(string printerName, string paperSizes, bool landscape)
        {
            this.landscape = landscape;
            this.printerName = printerName;
            this.paperSizes = paperSizes;

            document = new PrintDocument();
            permission = new PrintingPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            permission.Level = PrintingPermissionLevel.AllPrinting;//permisos para las impresoras

            document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = landscape;//horizontal o vertical
            document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;//nombre de la impresora que utilizaremos

            foreach (PaperSize item in document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
            {
                if (item.PaperName.Equals(paperSizes))
                {
                    document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = item;//configuramos el tamaño de papel
                    break;
                }
            }

            document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(FormatoImpresion);//configuramos el evento

        }

        private void FormatoImpresion(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)//creamos la impresion
        {
            Font fuente;
            const int CONST_Y = 15;//constante eje Y
            const int CONST_X = 50;//constante eje X
            int y = 0;//eje Y
            int cont = 1;

            fuente = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);//asignamos el tipo de fuente
            e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0}", "Prueba de impresión"), fuente, Brushes.Black, CONST_X, y, new StringFormat());//dibujamos la impresón

            y = CONST_Y * cont;//asignamos la nueva posición a eje Y
            cont++;//Incrementamos el contador

        }

        public void PrintDocument()
        {
            document.Print();//imprimimos el documento
        }
}
```

Comment: crees que me podrias dar un peque#o ejemplo de como definir el formato del papel? ando algo perdido la verdad

Comment: Primero crea un formato de impresión https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzf3pSWYGgY ahi te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo, luego en el código que te deje, solo seleccionas el formato que tu quieres utilizar. Se le pasa el nombre del formato como por ejemplo "carta"

Comment: me marca un error en el metodo "Print" dice que el metodo debe de tener un tipo de valor devuelto

Comment: si estas utilizando la clase tal como te la deje solo deberias invocar desde otra clase.
Print printer = new Print("Microsoft Print to PDF", "Carta", false);
printer.PrintDocument();